# Windows installer to install browser-extensions

Tags: windows, browser, installation

I'm trying to create an installer for windows (and potentially mac) that can install a browser extension for chrome, firefox, and for IE, and I'm totally stuck. Primarily I live in web-development land and I don't even really know where to start. This installer might eventually also include something like a bing toolbar for a kickback to us on a per-install basis. I'm hoping for something that doesn't require us to learn how to author a windows installer, but if that is unavoidable what are some good services / apps we could use?

Any help, would be GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

- Firefox:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Adding_Extensions_using_the_Windows_Registry
- Chrome:  http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/external_extensions.html#registry

The WiX toolkit and community may be a good place to start wrt IE.

I presume that you are imagining something like LastPass's installer

Comment: It's [no more possible with Firefox 73+](https://extensionworkshop.com/documentation/publish/distribute-sideloading/#standard-extension-folders)

Answer (score 0):

For Windows there is probably not much you can do to avoid using Windows Installer, therefore I recommend that you take a look at [Wix](http://wix.sourceforge.net/), which is an open source toolset from Microsoft for generating installers that will shield you from a lot of problems.

I don't have any first hand experience with installing browser plugins but I am guessing that installing your plugins isn't all that different from installing a regular program - you need to place a bunch of files and set some registry keys and so on. What registry keys and so on should be documented by the browser developer (and you probably already know this since you have done your plugins).

Unfortunately, I cannot help you when it comes to the Mac.