# How to install extension on client's chrome browser, while web site hit/browse

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

How to install extension on client's chrome browser, If my web site hit/browse by user.

Thanks,

Pravin

Answer (score 0):

[It looks like](https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/answer/2664769?hl=en) the cleanest way to do this is to publish your extension to the chrome web store and then use [inline installation](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/inline_installation).

Comment: To add to your answer, a quote from the docs: _"This function [installation] can only be called in response to a user gesture, for example within a click event handler; an exception will be thrown if it is not."_ Therefore, you cannot automatically initiate the install.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. Can i install extension to chrome along with my app installation?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630422/windows-installer-to-install-browser-extensions or https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions